# Animation In Silverlight Created With Expression Blend 4

Tags: silverlight, blend

I don't even know if this question belongs on SO - but I thought I'd give it a shot.  I'm trying to make a very, very simple animation in Expression Blend (I'm following a tutorial).  It's a ball that moves across the screen.

Inside Blend, if I press the 'play' button, the animation works great.  If I press f5 it opens a web browser and shows the Silverlight control, but the animation never begins.  It's just the first frame.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, wrong, maybe a simple oversight - in the Load event handler of your Silverlight control, place a line of code that begins the animation.

Comment: This is 100% correct and I feel silly for missing it.  For anyone else in my shoes - the code you are looking for is the .Begin() method on your storyboard.

Comment: Also if you don't want code behind, you can attach a `ControlStoryboardAction` to your layout root, and select the Storyboard's name and fire it in the `Loaded` event. All the work can be done inside Blend.